# Send info from javascript dialog to php

Tags: javascript, php

I get info in javascript dialog like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<script>

    var myInfo = prompt("Please enter info", "");
    if (myInfo != null) {
        //Here is my info
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I send this "myInfo" to PHP file (in the same server of javascript file) via GET, POST or by other method?

Comment: Use ajax to post data to php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy with [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp),

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$data=$_GET['data'];
//Do something with it
echo 'Response';
die();
?>
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<script>

    var myInfo = prompt("Please enter info", "");
    if (myInfo != null) {
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
       {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
               var response=xmlhttp.responseText;
               //Do someting with it
            }
       }
       xmlhttp.open("GET","/file.php?data="+myInfo,true);
       xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using native ajax you can use jquery and ajax to send data like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var myInfo = prompt("Please enter info", "");
    if (myInfo != null) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "php_page.php",
          data: {
            info: myInfo
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            alert( "data sent" );
          }
        });
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You will have to use jquery.js inorder to use this ajax functionality. On your php page you can directly refer the variable using $_REQUEST method as below

```
<?php
$data= $_REQUEST['info'];
?>
```

for more info on how jquery works you can refer to [jquery.com](http://jquery.com)